# Trying to get sum of a value in a table where where condition is multiple tables

Tags: sql, join

I'm facing a problem where i want to see sum of a field in table ve.

```
select sum(ve.[Cost Posted to G_L]) CPGL, sum(ve.[Expected Cost Posted to G_L]) ECPGL from [ICTL | HYDERABAD$Value Entry] ve
left join [ICTL | HYDERABAD$G_L - Item Ledger Relation] glr on 
ve.[Entry No_] = glr.[Value Entry No_] 
left join [ICTL | HYDERABAD$G_L Entry] ge on
glr.[G_L Entry No_] = ge.[Entry No_] 
left join [ICTL | HYDERABAD$G_L Account] ga on
ge.[G_L Account No_] = ga.No_
where ga.No_ = '200610' and ve.[Posting Date] < '03-01-2017'
group by ga.No_
```

Below is example
Table ve

```
Entry No. | CPGL | ECPGL | Posting Date
1      10   0   01-02-2017
2      15   0   10-02-2017
3      0    20  10-02-2017
4      0    25  02-03-2017
```

Table glr

```
Value Entry No. |   G/L Entry No.
1           1
1           2
2           3
2           4
3           5
3           6
4           7
4           8
```

Table ge

```
Entry No.   |   G/L Account No.
1       200610
2       200110
3       200650
4       200110
5       200610
6       200110
7       200610
8       200110
```

Table ga

```
No. |   Name
200610      RM A/c
200620      FG A/c
200630      BO A/c
200110      Bal A/c
```

Result required is 30

Comment: You wanna get some of what?

Comment: sum of CPGL+ECPGL. please note date in query is mm-dd-yy. and in table it is shown in dd-mm-yy